# PyUSB not recognizing particular USB device

Tags: python, python-2.7, libusb, pyusb

I am writing software in python to detect cosmic muons using a USB-connected radiation detector.

I am trying to use the PyUSB module to interact with the device, but PyUSB is not finding my radiation detector in particular. The device itself has a serial port, but I am using FTDI USB/serial adapter, and I have cross-checked the VID/PID for the adapter with the company and in control panel.

The following code yields `<generator object device-iter at 0x02AADA80>`. This is one of four USB devices on my PC (mouse, keyboard, WiFi adapter, and radiation detector).

```
import usb
import usb.core
import usb.util

dev = usb.core.find(find_all=True)
if dev is None:
    raise ValueError("device not found")
else:
    print(dev)
```

The code from the PyUSB tutorial I was using to locate the device also failed:

```
import usb
import usb.core
import usb.util

dev  usb.core.find("idVendor="0x0403", idProduct="0x6001") # VID/PID verified by company
if dev is None:
    raise ValueError("device not found")
else:
    print(dev)
```

I am running Python 2.7.1 on Windows 7, and I have the latest editions of PyUSB and libusb. I can't seem to find a reason why my device can't be found, although I'm probably missing something very fundamental.

Comment: What do you see on `usb.core.find()` and `usb.core.show_devices()`

Comment: Is the device driver for the detector possibly not compatible with PyUSB?

Comment: There are definitely too many quotation marks in your `usb.core.find` call. AFAIR you have to give the values as hex ints and not as strings. Just try to remove the quotation marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't realize PyUSB requires a driver (.inf file) for each device you want to interact with python; I assumed the automatic driver installation on Windows would suffice. The Windows Installer for libusb comes with a very convenient INF creator and installer, and the problem was resolved after I applied that tool.

Comment: Could not install 'unsigned INF' generated by libusb's  inf-wizard tool. Had to run following oneliner/commands.

bcdedit /set loadoptions DDISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS & bcdedit /set testsigning on

Answer (score 1):

Your code on line `dev  usb.core.find("idVendor="0x0403", idProduct="0x6001")` has the following mistakes:

1. Missing `=`. Change it to `dev = usb.core.find....`
2. Extra `"` at `find("idVendor`
3. According to [PyUSB doc](https://github.com/walac/pyusb/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst), you might want to try `dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x0403, idProduct=0x6001)`

Comment: Thanks. I changed my code based on your suggestions, but it still doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: What do you see on usb.core.find() and usb.core.show_devices()?  Before doing anything via PyUSB, you need to make sure that the device is visible from Windows.

Comment: Substituting usb.core.find() returns the value error, and usb.core.show_devices() returns nothing at all. But usb.core.find(find_all=True) returns <generator object device_iter at 0x02AF1A80>.

Comment: Got it figured out - PyUSB doesn't like the windows driver. I highly appreciate your help though.